# iOS App can't pair matter device by using system Matter.framework in Testflight

Tags: app-store, testflight

I built an App to pair Matter device. I'm not using the opensource matter sdk, I'm using the Matter.framework inner iOS system.

And it works perfectly in development. As it following the guid, enable developer mode, install developer profile.
guide:https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mattersupport/adding-matter-support-to-your-ecosystem?language=objc

But when I release the app in Testflight, disable developer mode, remove developer profile, restart iPhone. Download the app from Testflight, it just can't pair Matter device as it in developement.

And then, I found another guide, which mentioned that "Reminder: This is only needed for Application Development".

https://github.com/project-chip/connectedhomeip/blob/master/docs/guides/darwin.md#profile-installation

The system of iPhone is 17.1.1

So my question is, does it means My app can pair matter device successfully after releasing in AppStore without enabling develop mode?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to deploy the app from and external service (such as [diawi](https://www.diawi.com/)) rather than TestFlight to test properly